# Angular 15 environment.ts change

Tags: angular, angular15

Can anyone explain to me why Angular 15 doesn't automatically create the files: environment.ts
I understand this changed from version 14 to 15
More I did not understand the reason for this change, forcing to create manually, a standard thing.

an explanation of my doubt, the solution I already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/angular-15-what-happened-to-environmentts-koh) explains very well the why angular team chose to remove those files.

Angular uses a new way to tell `main.ts` that applicaiton is running in dev / prod mode, removing the need of having environment.ts in the first place as stated in the [article](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/angular-15-what-happened-to-environmentts-koh)

Answer (score 1):

I wanna add something to complement @Ninii's post: Since **Angular CLI 15.1.x** it is possible (very easy) to create the environments again:

`ng g environments` (or long version: `ng generate environments`) - Thats all. Read more about here: [Angular CLI](https://angular.io/guide/build)

> The project's src/environments/ directory contains the base configuration file, environment.ts, which provides configuration for production, the default environment. You can override default values for additional environments, such as development and staging, in target-specific configuration files.

[image]